# Animate input width from right to left framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to make my input appears with an animation making its width size going from `0` to `50%`. For this, I've used `framer-motion`. I've managed to make the animation but by default it's growing from the left to the right. Is there any way I could make it change to have it growing from the right to the left ?
[sandbox simple reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-booth-b9bnhl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>toggle input</button>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 25 }}>
        {toggle && (
          <motion.input
            initial={{ width: "0%" }}
            animate={{ width: "50%" }}
            transition={{ duration: 1, origin: 1 }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's not the best way of doing this but I think changing the following should fix your problem. Added `x` with `50vw` = 50% of viewport width (0vw = 0% width) for the `initial` "position" and for `animate` `x` with `0` for the ending position as well as width of `50vw`.

```
  <motion.input
    initial={{ width: "0vw", x: "50vw" }}
    animate={{ width: "50vw", x: 0 }}
    transition={{ duration: 1, origin: 1 }}
  />
```

You can find more details about it on the `API Documentation` of the `motion` component under `Value type conversion` https://www.framer.com/docs/component/##value-type-conversion.